# how to resize the text area  by another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text area and a div i want that when i click and move the div up or down the  text area also re-size, i.e. the div below the textarea should act as the vertical resize handle for the textarea.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to do something like what is seen here on stackoverflow. But please, post the relevant code for what you've already tried.

Comment: @MaxArt sorry i was mistaken its "move the div up or down the div"

Comment: @Zuul ya sir exactly , i dont have any idea sir how to do this i just need some hint.i dont need whole code

Comment: @Mayankswami The problem is that to get a nice effect, you have to resize the textarea on a `mousemove` event, but as long as we don't see some more of your code we can't really help.

Comment: Start trying. Ever used jQuery? Search on Google for the docs and start learning!

Comment: why not just use the browser provided resizer at the lower right corner of the textarea (like here in the comment box)? If you want to restrict the resize to vertical only, set resize: vertical css property of the textarea

Comment: @MukeshSoni Not every browser has that resizer. IE9, and more don't have it.

Comment: @Hidde no sir i never used jquery thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using Jquery UI you can make the bottom div draggable and use this to resize the textarea, I made a little jsfiddle for you which demonstrates this :)

http://jsfiddle.net/GspjK/